# how to redirect international users to English version of website using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, multilingual

I'm doing my first htaccess steps and going nowhere...

I have a site in German and English and I want to redirect all non German-speaking users to the English version of the site.

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs|da|el|en|es|et|fi|fr|ga|hr|hu|it|lt|lv|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|ru|sl|sr|sv) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.some.de/index.cfm?language=EN [R,L]
```

**Two questions:**
I'm in Germany with a browser set to German and I'm still redirected to the Englisch version. Why is that?
Will this have to be done for all subsequent pages in case the user starts out on some lower level page? Do I have to make a rewrite rule for every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm in Germany with a browser set to German and I'm still redirected to the Englisch version. Why is that?

Accept-Language is a mish-mash of language locales and values. Your browser probably also submits a bunch of other lang/locale pairs that gets matched in your regex (e.g. something like `en-ca,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,de-de;q=0.4,de;q=0.2`). What you could try doing is matching for *not* **de**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !de [NC]
```

> Will this have to be done for all subsequent pages in case the user starts out on some lower level page? Do I have to make a rewrite rule for every page?

Not sure how you've got your pages setup, but you could try changing your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?language=EN [R,L,QSA]
```

So requests for `/` gets redirected to `/?language=EN`, and `/somepath/` to `/somepath/?language=EN`, and `/file.cfm?someparam=value` to `/file.cfm?language=EN&someparam=value`

Comment: ah. this sounds good! thank you very much! first part is perfect (until I finish the french language version), second part should be ok. Some meddling I'll have to do anyway!